# ASM Bytecode Manipulation - Override visitLineNumber

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am new to the ASM Bytecode Manipulation tool. I am following the link - http://cs.ucla.edu/~msb/cs239-tutorial/

I have a java code which looks like below -

```
public static int m(int a, int b) {
    if (a < 2)
        a++; else b++;
    return a + b;
}
```

I want to visit each line in the code and I intend to use visitLineNumbers for the same.

It is processing "a++; else b++;" as a single line. I would like to override the  visitLineNumbers funtion to treat this line as 3 different lines as below -

```
if (a < 2)
  a++; 
else 
  b++;
return a + b;
```

I looked up the [API documentation](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/index.html) and tried using visitJumpInsn() but got an error. Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I had overridden the visitLineNumber as below -   @Override
 `public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
     mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
     mv.visitLdcInsn("line "+line+" executed");
     mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
     super.visitLineNumber(line, start);
 }  `  To make changes that I wanted I added `mv.visitJumpInsn(IF_CMPGE, start)`. It gave java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Comment: I may need to visit each instruction than just line numbers.

Comment: You can’t do arbitrary jumps within a method’s code. Besides, it’s not clear how that attempt to insert a jump instruction is connected with your question that only talks about line numbers. What do you *think* should happen when you do that?

Comment: As of now, I have the visitLine method overridden to sysout messages when each line is executed. But it skips the line where I have `a++ else b++` when the value of a is 3 since the condition is `if(a<2)` because it is in the same line in my java code. I realize that I may not be able to achieve this by the visitLine method. I will try to use a different function to trace the coverage of each instruction execution. I am sorry if I am not clear.